# How to find mongoose documents based on a string match on an array of substrings

Tags: javascript, regex, string, mongodb, mongoose

Say I have an array of substring search parameters, like this:

```
const subStrings = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "whatever"];
```

I have to find all documents where a field of type string contains **one or more** of the provided substrings.

So if I have a schema like this:

```
const sampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fieldOne: {
    type: String,
    ...
  }
});

const Sample = mongoose.model('Sample', sampleSchema);
```

I've seen this operation in other questions:

```
    Sample.find ({
         fieldOne: { $regex: substrings, $options: 'i' }
    })
```

But I've only seen it work if `substrings` is of type string, and not an array of strings.

Can this still be done with a modified regex, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a pipe-delimited regex pattern with the keywords list like this:

```
const subStrings = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "whatever"];
const regex = subStrings.join("|");


 Sample.find ({
   fieldOne: { $regex: regex, $options: 'i' }
});
```